# How can I launch Internet Shortcut created using WiX Installer on Exit Dialog?

Tags: web, wix, installation, shortcut

My WiX Installer basically creates Application Pool and Website in IIS and points to the MVC Project directory mentioned by me.

The current code is capable of creating Desktop & Start Menu Shortcuts.

I need a provision where the shortcut should be launched and website should open on completing the installation.

Following are my code snippets:

1) Defined Directories

```
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder"  Name="My Website"></Directory>
    </Directory>
<Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>
```

2) Start Menu & Desktop Shortcuts

```
<!--Start Menu & Desktop Shortcut-->
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
      <Component Id="MyApplicationShortcuts" Guid="{371A9D20-AD52-4A7F-AA93-8BD6EB6A5D04}">

        <util:InternetShortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut" Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="My App" Target="http://localhost:1234/"></util:InternetShortcut>

        <util:InternetShortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="My App" Target="http://localhost:1234/"></util:InternetShortcut>

        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Company\MyWebsite" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" On="uninstall"/>

      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
```

On installing, Desktop & Start Menu Shortcuts get created and can be launched on double clicking it.

3) Launch Application Checkbox on Exit Dialog

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch My Application" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1" />

    <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[#ApplicationDesktopShortcut]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" Directory="DesktopFolder" ExeCommand="http://localhost:1234/"/>
    <UI>
      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
```

On clicking Finish, the installer closes but the website doesn't get launched. Please Help!

P.S. My Desktop Shortcut name is **My App.lnk**
I also tried using following way:

```
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" Directory="DesktopFolder" ExeCommand="[DesktopFolder]My App.lnk /C My App.lnk" />
```

But, still no success. Please help me resolve this!

Comment: You can use custom action to start a process that in turn launch website.

Comment: @vinay
The custom action which I've used is not working. Can you modify it to work?
I need webpage shortcut created by Installer to get launched on finishing the installation.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need a shell exec to do this, as described here:

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/ui_and_localization/run_program_after_install.html

In particular this:
CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes"

because you want to do a shell open of the item.

Comment: Actually my Installer just creates a webpage shortcut on desktop. There is no .exe or .dll of the installer. 
I want that webpage shortcut to get launched on finishing the installation.

Comment: You misunderstand - a shell open will run the app associated with the file extension. So it works for any app, URL or txt file etc. Glad you got it working, but if you feel like experimenting give it a try. The WixShellExecTarget would be your web URL.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer myself.

**1. Created a CustomAction Project alongwith my Installer Project and added following:**

```
public static ActionResult LaunchMyApp(Session session)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://localhost:1234");
            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
```

**2. Updated my Installer's *Product* element in Product.wxs as follows:**

```
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch My Application" />
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX" Value="1" />

    <Binary Id="LaunchWebsiteCA" SourceFile="D:\Mandar\MyMVCApplication\WebsiteLaunch\bin\Debug\WebsiteLaunch.CA.dll"/>

    <CustomAction Id="LaunchWebsite" BinaryKey="LaunchWebsiteCA" DllEntry="LaunchMyApp" Return="check" Execute="immediate"></CustomAction>
    <UI>
      <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog" Control="Finish" Event="DoAction" Value="LaunchWebsite">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>
```

**3. Add reference of CustomAction Project into Installer Project**

Now I'm able to launch my Website on finishing the installation. :)